# How to get array input from multiple fields with same name (name = array[]) in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to allow users to enter multiple rows of items(eg lengths here) in the html

```
<td>
  <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm"
   name="length[]"
   ngModel>
</td>
```

But when I add multiple rows of the same field, I end up getting the last one. How can I get an array something like if I have 3 rows in the input with same name.

```
length = {
0 => 40,
1 => 50,
2 => 60
}
```

In laravel name = length[] would do the trick but I am not sure how to do the same thing in Angular

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such convention in Angular.

The Angular way to loop list objects inside HTML is with the `ngFor` directive.

***Example:***

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="item" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

TS

```
items = [0,0,0];
```

You can read more about `ngFor` [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngfor/).

Comment: But I dont have any "items" array, I want the user to enter it dynamically, (1 or more rows of items or length in this case)

Comment: Angular comes with data binding, you can use the `onchange` event or `ngModelChange` to hear for the changes and apply them to your objects as you wish.